# Mathematical expression evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dll, sqlclr

I've got a question about expression evaluation from string. Currently I'm working on project that requires to calculate mathematical expressions from strings that are stored in DB, I want to make C# method that evaluate this string, and this function will be run from stored procedure or function added to DB. So the problem is that I want to use in my C# function already created solutions like NCalc or Jace.Net, but if I want to run it from db I need to add dlls(for example NCalc.dll or Jace.dll) to db assembly. And adding those solutions are quite problematic, NCalc use unsafe code and Sql server cannot run methods from this dll, while Jace need many additional dlls that needs to be added to DB, this is not acceptable solution. So if any one knows working expression evaluator that can be added to db and run ? Thx in advance for help.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 2) and  .Net framework 4.5

Comment: How complex are your calculations? Simple + - / * ( ) can be done using XPathDocument, or you can write your own. These can be run without any third party dlls in managed code. See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/34349/how-to-evaluate-a-mathematical-expression-in-unity.html

Comment: Something like this:
int[] table = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] table2 = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 100 };
var output = Formula.Evaluate("[x] < 1 or [w] == 10", Formula.Evaluate("(Avg([x])) / [y] + Max([z])", table, 10, table2), 10);
It's quite complex, and in the future I need to be able use calculations like FFT or STDEV

Comment: Let say you have clr function "Evaluate". Could you  demonstrate how you are going to call it from T-SQL ? Many things should become clear. e.g. how you are going to pass array to CLR function?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij This is simple C# example, how I try to run expression evaluation
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
        public static SqlDouble FN_STD_Calc_Evaluate()
        {
            Expression exp = new Expression("2+2");
            return SqlDouble.Parse(exp.Evaluate().ToString());
        }
and this is code in sql:
select dbo.FN_STD_Calc_Evaluate()

And this is result:
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 
NCalc.EvaluationException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

Comment: And how you will pass the array to calculate avg? And what is wrong with calculating expression this way: DECLARE  @_sql nvarchar(max), @_base nvarchar(max)='SELECT ', @_expression nvarchar(max) = '2+2';
SET @_sql=@_base+@_expression; EXEC (@_sql) ?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Let's focus on this simple example that I provide You, application that are sing it is quite big, I'm web developer that need to implement it in this way that I wrote, it's a solution made by our system architects. We also have another solution that everything is in DB, but it is not so suitable for us, that's is way I'm trying this approach. Is there a way to run this simple example from db ?

Comment: OK, I get it you want to run it not just from db (for me it means T-SQL) but from CLR methods. Am I right that you want the dll that could be imported with SAFE persmission? Then I would get any open source evaluator, remove System.IO from references, and try to compile it.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Yes this is exactly that what I want to do. Ok, so You suggest that I should remove this reference, compile it and add created dll to db as assembly. I will try it at work, and let You know if it works.

Comment: Despite I propose to obesrve the sources, I am still sceptical about the perspectives... I have added important link to my answer, why I am sceptical.

Comment: And forget my proposal to remove System.IO refences - this doesn't solve CREATE ASSEMBLY checks problems -- (IO operations throws SecurityException on run time)/

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij
Hi, how can I set UNSAFE restriction to assembly, I'm doing it in this way:
`BEGIN TRY
  ALTER ASSEMBLY [NCalc] FROM '$(absAssemblyDllPath)\NCalc.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
END TRY
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM sys.assemblies 
     WHERE name = 'NCalc') BEGIN
  PRINT 'Create ASSEMBLY NCalc ...';
  CREATE ASSEMBLY NCalc FROM @vs_absAssemblyDll WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
END`
After deploy a data base in properties of added assembly, Permission set is set to "Unrestricted" and still cant run methods from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** I think you could include embed JavaScript engines to the circle of your interests..

e.g. http://jurassic.codeplex.com/ - pure dotnet, one dll, easy as pie (but still requires WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE/EXTERNAL_ACCESS, and I think any not specially desigden for CLR lib would require UNSAFE, e.g. it is enough to have static not-readonly field to became UNSAFE, other restrictions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx).

**B.** Don't forget that T-SQL is dynamic language as well. Why you can't just  save your expressions in T-SQL ? IMHO Sql Server much more suitable to run "Avg" than any expression evaluator that can be called throug CLR drain.

Comment: After reading article from link that You send me, everything become more clearly, NCalc use static properties for caching purpose. Static not readonly properties are forbidden if You want to add Your assembly as safe one, after doing some changing in code(removing static properties) everything works fine. There are many more restrictions when adding an assembly but it looks like in my case this one was crucial. Thx for help.

Comment: And last thing, You can change assembly permission sets in two ways:
1. from sql management studio, go to Database->Programmability->Assemblies->ex "Unrestricted" (can run assembly with static fields).
2. go to project(SQL Server Database project)->references->rmb on assebly->Permission Set -> Safe/External/Unsafe